# Configuring Maven Dependencies Dynamically

Tags: java, maven-plugin

I have several independent maven project for example:

Maven Project --> A
Maven Project --> B

I want to create a Separate Project --> C which is for picking a Project (A or B) and wrap is under a folder with some scripts which are common for both (A and B).

Now i want to configure Maven Project C dynamically with groupid and artifactid in such a way that I will specify the Group ID and Artifact Id while doing the maven C Project

Maven C Project --> mvn clean install -DgroupId="B" -DartifactId="B" and It will fetch the dependency from Maven Local Repository and build the Maven C.

Comment: What did you tried? What did go wrong?

Comment: I tried using maven assembly plugin . In maven assembly plugin I need to make artifact part of dependency set so that maven can pick it from .m2.
That's why i include both Project (A,B) as dependency in Maven C. and Code worked fine. 
Now Issue occurs when any of the dependency is missing in M2 lets say A is not present and I need to build only B. In this case maven is throwing Error.

Answer (score 0):

Maven designed to work with static dependency tree.

You can try something else. Like `sbt` or `gradle`. Both of them know how to work with maven repository.